# Getting a compile error- Basic Java applet

Tags: java

```
public class ShippingApplet extends Applet implements ItemListener
```

This gets me an error that says :

```
\Documents\Java assignments\Chap4 Commission\ShippingApplet.java:14: error: ShippingApplet is not abstract and does not override abstract method itemStateChanged(ItemEvent) in ItemListener
```

public class ShippingApplet extends Applet implements ItemListener

and I'm unsure what to do. Previously in all my other chapters, I just simply put what the name of the file is ("ShippingApplet" in this case) and I'm fine.

The program  you build during the chapter uses CommissionApplet and I can change it, and it works fine, as long as it matches the file name. Just unsure why I can't compile a stub here to see/test my layout.

Comment: The error message is common and means that while your class has been declared to implement an interface, the code does not in fact implement all the methods of the interface as is required. That you're asking suggests that you will want to brush up your understanding on how to use and declare interfaces, what they're for and all that, and I invite you to read the tutorials on the subject, including this one: [Tutorial: What is an Interface?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Comment: In your particular case, the interface is the `ItemListener`, and the error message (as is usually the case) tells you **exactly** what is wrong, what method is missing from your own code.

Comment: If the question and answer that were used to close your question doesn't fully answer things for you, I invite you to check out [these similar questions on this same subject that can be found on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+is+not+abstract+and+does+not+override+abstract+method+site:stackoverflow.com). In fact, please study the Google search used, since it is a decent way to search for answers to your questions before asking what likely will be a duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit over my head with this Java class but I got it figured out, thanks to your input.  I was unsure of exactly what to search for but thank you for getting me in the right direction.